# How to import pgp backup back into smartcard?

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp, smartcard

I generated a backup of my master key and 3 sub keys following [this](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide) into these archives:

```
gpg.conf
mastersub.key
openpgp-recovs.d
private-keys-v1.d (contains 4 .key files)
pubring.kbx
random_seed
reader_0.status
sub.key
tofu.db
trustdb.gpg
```

how can I put those back into my smartcard (yubikey)?

Comment: See if [this](https://www.sidorenko.io/post/2014/11/yubikey-or-openpgp-smartcards-for-newbies/) helps, along with the manpage for gpg. It has a command bkuptocard which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Sebastian unfortunately it isn't clear how to use `bkuptocard` with my backup files (they are not in pgp format) and I my pgp doesn't have this command

Comment: Ok, if you followed the tutorial you linked you probably have the keys in exported format. Have you tried importing them with "gpg --import mastersub.key"?